# Running Flask in Windows doesn't see environment variable

Tags: python, windows, flask, environment-variables

I want to set an environment variable `DATABASE_URL` that will be read by my Flask app to connect to the database. I use `set DATABASE_URL = '...'`, but I get an error that the variable is not set when I do `flask run`. Why isn't this working?

```
import os

from flask import Flask
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

app = Flask(__name__)

if not os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"):
    raise RuntimeError("DATABASE_URL is not set")

engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
```

I navigate to the installed directory for project1 and do the following in Windows 10 cmd.exe:

```
set FLASK_APP = application.py
set FLASK_DEBUG = 1
set DATABASE_URL = 'postgres.......' (the credential given by the Heroku account)
flask run
```

Flask runs, I go to `localhost:5000`, and get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\learningPython\web_CS50\project1\application.py", line 12, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError("DATABASE_URL is not set")
RuntimeError: DATABASE_URL is not set
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove spaces from set command

```
set FLASK_APP=application.py
set FLASK_DEBUG=1
set DATABASE_URL='postgres.......'
```

More at https://ss64.com/nt/set.html

Comment: Holy crap I can't believe that worked.  Also, I had to put in the connection string with no quotes at all. e.g.:           set DATABASE_URL=postgres.......

Answer (score 0):

A quick idea to try:

1. On Windows, use `setx` instead of `set` to modify the system environment variables.

   setx FLASK_APP = application.py
2. Start a new command processor to see the variables reflected in your environment (They get set when the shell is initialized).

Answer (score 0):

```
set FLASK_APP=application.py
set FLASK_DEBUG=1
set DATABASE_URL='postgres.......' (WITHOUT THE QUOTATION MARKS, because the system put it automatically, I opened a notepad and set the password and copy paste and execute in powershell
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set your path in your pc's environmental varibles.
You can find your path of the python here C:\Users"your default user name "\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39.
after setting up path use

1. pip3 install

Answer (score -1):

Personally, when i used flask run, i had an issue. I get this message "'flask' is not recognized as an internal or external, operable program or batch file" what could be the issue.